# How to put an array of array into another array in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, dictionary

```
var dic: [String: [[Item]]] //dic with string key and value of array in array of my Class Object
```

How can i take the values from this dic and store it in an array as this:

```
var array: [[Item]]//Array of array
```

How can I store the values from dic Into this array I tried using the for(key, value) statement. But it wouldn't let me append the values to the array variable. If you need more information I'm happy to give it, but if you understand what I'm trying to do and you know how to do it I appreciate your answer and it's very much needed!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the values in dictionary use `dictionary.values`, it will return you an array of all the values.

```
 var array = dic.values
```

If you want to go through each value in the dictionary use the following:

```
for value in dic.values {
   // println("Value: \(value)")
   array.append(value)
}
```

Comment: it's not working.  I thought it would but i think im having a problem bevause the value is an array of arrays at each index and I think thats where the code is having issues.  Is there something I gave to do when inserting basically matric array?

Answer (score 0):

For your first line i give you suggestion that you should create your dictionary by

```
var array = ["123","456","789"]
var array1 = NSMutableArray()
array1 .addObject(array)
var dict = ["String":array1]
var array3 :NSArray  = dict["String"]!
println("value ::\(array3[0])")
```

Output that you get is::
**"value ::(\n    123,\n    456,\n    789\n)"**

May this help you